# Размещение <div> внутри <canvas>

Tags: html, css, canvas

Я размещаю div внутри элемента холста, как показано ниже:

```
<canvas>
    <div></div>
</canvas>
```

Здесь у них обоих есть высота и ширина. Но здесь я не вижу `div`!

Разве нельзя использовать `div` или `p` на `canvas`?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Placing a div within a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5763911/7394871) от участника  [@thecodeparadox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690854/thecodeparadox).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/5763911/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вы не можете размещать элементы внутри `canvas` (и отображать оба элемента); они отображаются только в том случае, если браузер не понимает элемент `canvas`.

Если вы хотите расположить элементы в той же области, что и canvas, вот один из множества способов, который позволит вам это сделать:

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#canvas-wrap { position:relative } /* Сделайте это позиционированным родителем */
#overlay     { position:absolute; top:20px; left:30px; }
```

Вот еще один метод, который позволяет содержимому div нормально перемещаться и делает canvas фоном для содержимого:

**CSS**

```
#canvas-wrap { position:relative; width:800px; height:600px }
#canvas-wrap canvas { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0 }
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5764395/7394871) от участника  [@Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Вот еще один метод, который позволяет содержимому div нормально
> перемещаться и делает canvas фоном для содержимого:
>
> **CSS**

```
> #canvas-wrap { position:relative; width:800px; height:600px }
> #canvas-wrap canvas { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0 }
```

Попробовал этот вариант реализовать, когда `canvas` находится внутри `div`

```
<div id="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="350"></canvas>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPcfs.jpg";
img1.onload = drawImages;

function drawImages() {
 context.drawImage(img1, 20, 20, 300, 350);
}
```

```css
#canvas-wrap { position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;border:1px solid; }
#canvas-wrap canvas { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
#overlay {
position:relative;
margin:2em;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius:50%;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="350"></canvas>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: По большому счету `canvas` - это изображение, динамически создаваемое, но просто изображение. В итоге вопрос звучит так: **как разместить <div> внутри <img>**. Визуально `<canvas>` имеет закрывающий тег и якобы отличается от `<img>`, но *Custom Elements* обязаны иметь закрывающий парный тег, а кастомность здесь - условие для обратной совместимости для браузеров, не поддерживающих Canvas. Так, что это условность. Поэтому насколько можно считать "натягиванием" других элементов на холст размещением в нем? Ровно настолько, насколько элемент размещается в <img>.

Comment: @Leonid Кстати ты заметил, что это была реализация варианта из ответа EnSO?  Также мне это очень напомнило, когда SVG оборачивается в DIV

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое между открывающим и закрывающим тегами `<canvas>` будет проигнорировано браузером, если поддерживается Canvas API. В противном случае тег будет распознан, как пользовательский (теперь уже невалидный пользовательский, т.к. не содержит `-`) со стилями и поведением `inline` элемента (по умолчанию).

```html
<canva><div>Ваш браузер не поддерживает тег <i>canvas</i>.<br> Установите современный браузер и наслаждайтесь крутыми фишками.<br> <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/">Скачать правильный браузер!</a></div></canva>
<canvas><div>Canvas игнорирует "содержимое"</div></canvas>
```